# A program that prints text into a text file

Tags: python

I need to create a program that takes in user's i.d numbers to create a school registration system and then export the information into a .txt file.  My problem is I'm failing to write each i.d. number entered onto a new line and I need help in doing that.

I have placed each i.d. into a list, then joined them all into a string. Now I need to print each i.d. number in the string on a separate line. Please tell me where to insert the "\n" so it prints on a new line in the txt file.

```
# we first define the name of the file and set it to write mode
to_file = open("RegForm.txt" , "w")

# list variable for storing the received i.d. numbers
id_numbers = []

# asking the user to enter the number of students that will write the exam
num = int(input("Please enter the number of students that will sit for the exam: "))



# creating a loop that iterates over every student who is writing the exam
# we then append the list of id numbers with each new input we receive

for toFile in range(0, num):
    id_numbers.append(input("Enter your ID Number: " ))

# we create the variable string_of_nums which is joining the list into a single string
string_of_nums = " ".join(id_numbers)

# writing the id numbers onto the text file
to_file.write(string_of_nums)

# closing the file
to_file.close()
```

I need it to print each i.d. number on a separate line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current string_of_nums separates each student ID with a space.

```
string_of_nums = " ".join(id_numbers)
```

**join() Definition and Usage**

> The join() method takes all items in an iterable and joins them into one string.
>   A string must be specified as the separator.

So whatever is inside the "" will be your string separator.

So to separate each student with a linebreak we must insert *\n*:

```
string_of_nums = "\n".join(id_numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

`string_of_nums = "\n".join(id_numbers)`

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the newline character (`'\n'`) at the end of each line, so use newline as the join string when you join the lines together.

```
string_of_nums = "\n".join(id_numbers)
```